# EventListener adds new fields but Controller doesn't recognize them

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to add new fields to my form depending on the selected value from a list. My problem comes when clicking on *"submit"*, after the code runs the `eventListener` method (in which the new field is added), the controller gets the form without the new field! I'm struggling to understand where the problem is.

Here's my form builder:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('DataTypeList', ChoiceType::class, [
        'required' => false,
        'mapped'   => false,
        'choices'  => [
            "String Type"   => "DataTypeString",
            "Monetary Type" => "DataTypeMonetaryNumber"
        ],
        'attr'     => ['style' => 'width: 50vw'],
    ]);

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        if ($data['DataTypeList'] === "DataTypeString") {
            $form->add("DataTypeString", TextType::class, [
                'required'       => true,
                'mapped'         => false,
                'error_bubbling' => true,
                'attr'           => [
                    'placeholder' => 'This is an example',
                    'style'       => 'width: 50vw'
                ]
            ]);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my controller:

```php
$form = $this->createForm('data\AddType', $data, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('data_add', [
        'dataKey_id' => $data->getDataAccessKey()->getId(),
        'returnRoute' => $returnRoute
    ]),
    'method' => 'POST',
));

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    //Here I make a dump() on $request that shows that my form only contains 'DataTypeList'
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```php
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        dump($form->get('DataTypeString')->getData()); //return null;
    }
```

It is return null, because you add your field in `PRE_SUBMIT` and you don't set data, but there is no excpetion, so `DataTypeString` field exist.

## UPDATE

PRE_SUBMIT event is executed before the submit action in PHP.

This is the process

1. Create form and build
2. Set Data to the form (this data is the second parameters of createForm method in your controller)
3. Build form view and display the form on the browser
4. You fill your form on your browser and submit data
5. When you handleRequest in your controller, he looks in $_POST variable and see that you click on the 'submit' button of your form, he execute PRE_SUBMIT event **HERE**, and he do $form->submit and POST_SUBMIT event
6. In POST_SUBMIT he validate the form and set errors on the form fields
7. If your form is not valid you don't enter in `if($form->isValid())` and you build the form view. And this time you have the *DataTypeString* fields in your form, because PRE_SUBMIT add the field

Why do you want to add this field in `PRE_SUBMIT` ?

Comment: I also get null but where is DataTypeString located then? my dump keep throwing me only DataTypeList:

+request: ParameterBag {#10 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "add" => array:2 [▼
        "DataTypeList" => "DataTypeString"
        "_token" => "8bI1iK1r-LDlMI"
      ]
    ]
  }

Comment: IMO This is not 'submit' directly from the form, so the data isn't in $_POST variable, so isn't in request. You send the form, after the listener add the form item to the form, but not in Request.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, they made me realize about my mistake (checking the $request variable instead of $form). I add the field during pre_submit because I don't want the form to consider it as valid, hence refreshing the page with the new form field.